# Sort datagridview by created columns. Entity Framework c# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, entity-framework-4, datagridview

I´m having a problem, I retrieve all the Loans I have stored in my database like this:

```
list_loans = db.Loan.Where(x => x.State.id_state != 6).ToList();
```

db is the Object context.

Then, I assign that list as the DataSource for my DataGridView.

```
dgv_Loans.Datasource = list_loans;
```

With that info, I add some columns. Like for example, installments left to pay. I get that value by counting the result of a query.

The user can order the result using some options. Is easy to order the result from the fields that the entity have (using linq), but I dont know how to order the results using this new columns.

I read some posts here and tried this:

```
dgv_Loans.Sort(dgv_Loans.Columns["installments_left"], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

By doing this, I´m getting the following exception at runtime:

"DataGridView control must be bound to an IBindingList object to be sorted."

Is there anyway to use linq to orderby created columns in a DataGridViewColumn? Or how can I solve this error?

I know there are related posts, but after reading them, I can´t find a solution to this specific problem. Thats why I showed how I implemented to get some advice..

Answer (score 1):

Rather than binding directly to the list retrieved from database, what I generally do is have a view class and have all the calculated properties in that class

```
public class LoanView : Loan {
  public LoanView(Loan loan){
  }
  public int InsallmentsLeft { get { return ...; } }
}
```

and then bind the datasource to a list of this, this keeps sorting working.

Comment: Thanks, but isn´t any other way to do it by using the created columns? Can I create the comparer when I create the column?

Comment: The other way is to do this via custom sorting. more info at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171608.aspx

Comment: But I´m having the same exception :/

Comment: Did you use the sortcompare event or did you implement the IComparer interface, it would help if you post the code of the sort implementation

Comment: I give the user lots of filtering options, I think the best way to solve it by using your view class.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning about *Sort datagridview by created columns* using Entity Framework

I guess you need this [Presenting the `SortableBindingList<T>`](http://www.timvw.be/2008/08/02/presenting-the-sortablebindinglistt-take-two/)

***Usage:***

```
loanBindingSource.DataSource = new SortableBindingList<Loan>(list_loans.ToList());
dgv_Loans.Datasource = loanBindingSource;
```

Comment: I´m getting this error: The type or namespace name 'SortableBindingList' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). I cannot resolve it by right clicking it.

Comment: yes, have you already downloaded the Class([SortableBindingList<T>](http://www.timvw.be/wp-content/code/csharp/SortableBindingList.zip))?

Comment: Ok I downloaded the class, added it to my project and wrote that line of code. Now, I´m getting the next error: "A data-bound DataGridView control can only sort on columns bound to data. Parameter name: DataGridViewColumn"

Comment: sorry im wrong, you must use the BindingSource as stated from the link. :)

Comment: What is loanBindingSource?

Comment: `loanBindingSource` is BindingSource of your `DataGridView`(_dgv_Loans_)

Comment: Same error. I think I´m having this error because the columns I want to sort by are created after the DataSource assignment. The columns do not belong to a field of each element of the list, I create it after in runtime.

Comment: yes, you must set the `DataSource` of your `dgv_Loans`, and you don't need to create a Column by runtime, you can do this in design time and this is advisable if you have a Class(`Loan`).

Comment: Then Naresh Jois option will be more suitable. I can user linq and will not need this new class..

Comment: well, you must to think again, if you want a sorted column using linq statement you have to follow the rule and thats recommended `:)`

Comment: Yep. I wish it were easier :/ Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
int ID = Convert.ToInt32(cmbDepartments.SelectedValue);
var EmployeeList = from Employee in db.Employee
    where Employee.DepartmentID == ID
    select new
    {
        Employee.FirstName,
        Employee.LastName
    };
dataGridView1.DataSource = EmployeeList.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could directly give the data source to `dataGridView1.DataSource` but you must write `ToList()` at the end of your query:

```
int ID = Convert.ToInt32(cmbDepartmanlar.SelectedValue);

dataGridView1.DataSource = (from Employee in db.Employee
                            where Employee.DepartmentID == ID
                   select new
                   {
                       Employee.FirstName,
                       Employee.LastName
                   }).ToList();
```